# Customizing the color of bootstrap's navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I haven't touched the core bootstrap files - in my own CSS I have the following:

```
#menu-bar div {
    border-color: #0072A6;
    background-color: #0072A6;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu-bar .navbar {
    border-color: #0072A6;
    background-color: #0072A6;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu-bar .navbar-inner {
    border-color: #0072A6;
    background-color: #0072A6;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
}

#menu-bar p, #menu-bar a {
    color: white;
}

#menu-bar .active a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0072A6;
}
```

This has gotten me where I want for screens > 1024px wide, however something in the responsive bootstrap css is causing this black border to wrap the menu for smaller screens:

[image: rogue border]

Does anyone know how I can remove this?  I've made a fiddle of it here including bootstrap to make it easier to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/AmZ5L/

I'm also trying to figure out how to customize that button color in case anyone's feeling super generous with their time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.navbar-inverse .btn-navbar` is what defines your button color.

`.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner` is what defines the black border.

Comment: I think I'm doing something stupid.  Can you show me on a fddle fork?

Comment: I got the border fixed up per the answer below, but the button is still black :/

Comment: @JakeP http://jsfiddle.net/AmZ5L/2/ will show you a red button. For the black border it's the `background-image` rules that are applied to `.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner`

Answer (score 2):

Add `background-image: none;` to your `#menu-bar .navbar-inner` style. This will override the bootstrap style that is giving the black border (`.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner` in bootstrap-combined.css).

To change the colour of the button, override the `.navbar-inverse .btn-navbar` style:

```
.navbar-inverse .btn-navbar
{
    background: red;
}
```